# Automapper String to Guid not working

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper, guid

I'd like to create a generic type converter that converts a Guid to a string and a string to a Guid depending on which direction I'm converting (DTO > VM or VM > DTO). Additionally, some properties have nullable Guids so I thought I could handle that too. I've tried the following with not luck:

```
CreateMap<string, Guid?>().ConvertUsing(value => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? Guid.Parse(value) : (Guid?)null);
CreateMap<string, Guid>().ConvertUsing(guid => Guid.Parse(guid));
```

and

```
CreateMap<Guid?, string>().ConvertUsing(guid => guid?.ToString("N"));
CreateMap<Guid, string>().ConvertUsing(guid => guid.ToString("N"));
```

Any suggestions on how I can get this to work?

Comment: Why do you have no luck with your try? Does not compile, which error? Does not work at runtime, which exception?

Comment: What version of automapper are you using? There was an issue logged about this a while ago: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/523

Comment: Using v6.1.1. Not error returned from automapper. I just get a null reference on the property because it's not converting the string to GUID.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works on my computer:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<string, Guid>().ConvertUsing(s => Guid.Parse(s));
    cfg.CreateMap<string, Guid?>().ConvertUsing(s => String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s) ? (Guid?)null : Guid.Parse(s));
    cfg.CreateMap<Guid?, string>().ConvertUsing(g => g?.ToString("N"));
    cfg.CreateMap<Guid, string>().ConvertUsing(g => g.ToString("N"));
});

var guid = Guid.NewGuid();
var guidStr = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

var guid1 = Mapper.Map<Guid>(guidStr);     // The guid is parsed successfully
var guid2 = Mapper.Map<Guid?>(null);       // Gets null as expected
var str1 = Mapper.Map<string>(guid);       // The guid is serialized successfully
var str2 = Mapper.Map<string>(null);       // Gets null as expected
```

Do you configure your Mapper like this, using the `Initialize` method?

It also works using the `Mapper.Instance.Map` methods instead of `Mapper.Map` directly.

Answer (score 6):

If the default string format is good enough, this works by default in both directions, no type converters needed.

Comment: default mapping works only for Guid, not nullable type (Guid?).

Comment: That works too, perhaps you're on an older version.